# Will a never fulfilled promise cause a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, memory, memory-leaks

this question is not new on SO, but I have a scenario that is not exactly the same as other questions.

Let's say I have a class `Component`

```
class Component {
  constructor() {
    this.resolvers = [];
  }

  addResolver() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.resolvers.push(resolve);
    });
  }

  callResolvers() {
    this.resolvers.forEach((resolver) => resolver());
  }
}
```

Then I have this snippet of code

```
let components = [];

async function addComponent() {
  const component = new Component();

  components.push(component);

  await component.addResolver();

  console.log("resolver called");
}

function deleteComponents() {
  components = [];
}

function resolveComponents() {
  components.forEach((component) => component.callResolvers());
}

addComponent();
addComponent();
addComponent();

resolveComponents();
```

If I call `resolveComponents()` the resolvers are called.

My concern is if instead of `resolveComponents()`, I call `deleteComponents()`, like this:

```
addComponent();
addComponent();
addComponent();

deleteComponents();
```

Will that garbage collect the components?

They have unfulfilled promises, the resolvers for these promises are stored in the `component.resolvers`.

Since the previous components will be impossible to reach after the deletion, my guess is that they will be collected even though they have unfulfilled promises.

What's the answer to this?

Comment: Maybe I'm being dense, but I don't see any unfulfilled/unresolved/pending promises in the given code.

Comment: @evolutionxbox sorry, I edited the question adding the `deleteComponents` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no circular dependencies, and calling `deleteComponents` lets go of the only reference you have to them. So the components won't be leaked

Comment: Yes, there are not circular dependencies. Accepting this since it answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

A `Promise` is just a regular object, so if there are no more references to it, then it gets cleared by the garbage collector (even if in pending state). If a `Promise` resolves later, then obviously there is a reference to it somewhere. For example in this code:

```
new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 999999));
```

Even if we don't store the `Promise` in a variable, `setTimeout` keeps a reference to the `resolve` function, which has an internal reference to `this`: the `Promise` instance. Then the `Promise` instance is kept alive until the delay ends.

In your example if you replace the components array with an empty one, the components can be garbage collected, along with their `resolvers` property which contains the only references to the Promises, so they can be collected as well.

If you have doubts about memory leaks, you can diagnose them easily by taking a snapshot of the memory with the "memory" tab of the browser's DevTools.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll check out the memory tab in DevTools.

Answer (score 1):

If there are not references to the promise, and it goes out of scope it will most likely be eligible for GC, although I'm not 100% certain that is the case. It is generally good practice to resolve any promises you have, so I'd suggest calling the resolvers before deleting the components.

Comment: Yes. It's a good practice to resolve any promise, but there are theses cases like this when the function that resolves the promises is never called.